# JSON serialization - set default value for int type

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I use the exist API and can't change it.

So I have some variable - CellProviderID.

It looks like it is an int, because when I set the int value the server returns the expected response.

```
"CellProviderID":5,"CellProviderID2":7,"CellProviderID3":2
```

The problem appears when I leave this value empty and after serialization I get:

```
"CellProviderID":0,"CellProviderID2":0,"CellProviderID3":0
```

because 0 is default value for int type. And the server returns an error:

> {"ErrorCode":10,"ErrorMessage":"Cell provider was specified, but cell number is blank, Pager provider was specified, but pager number is blank"}

So it looks rather like it's some enum, and 0 hasn't a value.

It works well when I change serialized json from

```
"CellProviderID":0,"CellProviderID2":0,"CellProviderID3":0
```

to

```
"CellProviderID":"","CellProviderID2":"","CellProviderID3":""
```

How should I initialize the properties to be able to setup int values and get "" when I leave this property empty?

```
[JsonProperty]
public int CellProviderID { get; set; }
[JsonProperty]
public int CellProviderID2 { get; set; }
[JsonProperty]
public int CellProviderID3 { get; set; }
```

Comment: how about trying to make your properties of type int? that way they can be null (and see how the serialization reacts to that)

Comment: they are integer. And default value for integer is 0 insted of null.

Comment: @iPogosov He means `int?`, not `int` with a question mark. `int?` is shorthand form for `Nullable<int>` which means the type can be `null` *or* an `int`. That is, change your property to : `public int? CellProviderID { get; set; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change return type of your properties from `int` to `int?`, so you will get `null` value as default.

It will be serialized as

```
"CellProviderID":null,"CellProviderID2":null,"CellProviderID3":null
```

so you can have a deal with that.

Next, you must change your serialization to ignore `null` values. If you're using `Json.Net`, you serialization must look like:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie,Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore })
```

So, your server will not receive non-initialized values

Answer (score 2):

You could optionally write a Custom JsonConverter and handle the custom serialization/deserialization yourself.

```
internal class Inherited
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}

internal class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Inherited);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var data = value as Inherited;
        if (data != null)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            foreach (var item in typeof(Inherited).GetProperties())
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(item.Name);
                switch (item.PropertyType.Name)
                {
                    case "Int32":
                        {
                            writer.WriteValue(default(int) == (int)item.GetValue(data, null) ? "" : item.GetValue(data, null).ToString());
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteEnd();
        }
    }
}

JsonSerializerSettings obj = new JsonSerializerSettings();
obj.Converters.Add(new CustomConverter());
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Inherited(0) { MyProperty = 0, MyProperty2 = 0 }, obj);
```

Results in -
    {"MyProperty":"","MyProperty2":""}

Comment: As I understand if I have in the Inherited class int properties, when I can set default int value(0), I will get always ""?

Comment: Give it a try. I think so.